# How to find the inverse/reverse implementation of a function in theory?

Tags: sequences-and-series, functions, inverse, integers, random

I have this concrete problem of reversing a function implementation: [How to reverse this random number from a sequence generator function?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4228344/how-to-reverse-this-random-number-from-a-sequence-generator-function) But what I'm wondering for this question right here is, what is the general theory for finding the reverse implementation of a function? What are the techniques, how do you do it? Maybe if I knew that I could figure out this concrete problem on my own. But as of now, I am completely in the dark how I would find a solution to this problem.

Comment: Inverting functions, or simply finding solutions to $f(x)=c$ for fixed $c$, is non-trivial.  Depending on the context, you might be able to find closed formulas, or you might be able to apply numerical methods, but there isn't any sort of universal solution.

Comment: Many functions used for generating pseudorandom numbers are designed to be difficult to reverse.  If there were a simple, easily reversed rule, the numbers wouldn't look like they're actually random.

Comment: Almost all mathematics is about inverting functions. If this task were easy, there wouldn't be math

Comment: Yeah but [my example](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4228344/how-to-reverse-this-random-number-from-a-sequence-generator-function) has the function going in one direction already defined, and we know by definition it is a one-to-one mapping. Isn't there a technique in mathematics to then take such a function and figure out its inverse/reverse in a straightforward way?

Comment: Knowing abstractly that a function is invertible doesn't give you a feasible way to invert it.  That's what cryptography and hash functions are based on: we don't store a password, we store it's hash. Even if the attacker gets the hash, and knows the hasting function. he won't be able to find the password that generates it . An exhaustive algorithm will invert the hasing function eventually for specific values, but the time complexity required for such a method makes it impractical.  RSA crypto is based on the fact that it's easier to multiply 2 large primes than it is to factor the result.

Comment: For a small function like the one defined in your example, it's feasible to compute all the pairs $(x, f(x))$ for all $x$ in the domain, build a table or array such that $table[f(x)] = x$, and use that as your inverse function. It's not clever, it's not time efficient, but that's simply the most general way to invert functions.